# Get POSIX epoch as system_clock::time_point

Tags: c++, time, epoch, std, c++-chrono

I'm aware that the default value of a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` is the clock's epoch, but I can't find any mandate in the C++11 standard that `system_clock`'s epoch is the same as the POSIX epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). Is it safe to assume on Linux and Windows that this is the case? Or would it be smarter to use `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(0)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard leaves the epoch of `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` unspecified.

There are three implementations of `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` I am aware of:

1. libc++
2. libstdc++
3. VS

All three of these are thin wrappers around [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which counts the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970,not counting leap seconds.

All of them are based on a signed 64 bit integral type.  None of them are steady.  libc++ has a tick period of microseconds.  libstdc++ has a tick period of nanoseconds, and VS has a tick period of 0.1 microseconds.

In case it is useful, [here is a paper](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) which demonstrates some formula to take advantage of the unspecified but common epoch to convert back and forth from the civil calendar without going through `time_t`.

The advantage of using `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t` is that it is guaranteed to work by the standard.  The disadvantage is that in practice it will limit you to the precision of a second (though that precision is unspecified).

The advantage of assuming the epoch of `std::chrono::system_clock` to be 1970-01-01, even though it is unspecified, is that you will be correct on all known implementations, and the precision available for this alternative is much higher than that provided by `time_t`.

---

**Update**

The draft C++2a spec now specifies `system_clock` to model [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> **26.7.1.1 Overview [time.clock.system.overview]**
>
> 1 Objects of type `system_clock` represent wall clock time from the system-wide realtime clock. Objects of type `sys_time<Duration>` measure time since (and before) 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC excluding leap seconds. This measure is commonly referred to as *Unix time*. This measure facilitates an efficient mapping between `sys_time` and calendar types (26.8). [*Example*: `sys_seconds{sys_days{1970y/January/1}}.time_since_epoch()` is `0s`. `sys_seconds{sys_days{2000y/January/1}}.time_since_epoch()` is `946’684’800s`, which is `10’957 * 86’400s`.
>   —*end example*]

And the synopsis ([time.syn]) has previously defined:

```
template<class Duration>
  using sys_time  = time_point<system_clock, Duration>;
using sys_seconds = sys_time<seconds>;
using sys_days    = sys_time<days>;
```

We are hopeful that the "a" in "C++2a" will be "0".